# Method or Data Member not found VB6

Tags: vb6

Hi i have a problem with VB6

VB 8 lighting

```
Public Sub AddText(ByVal Msg As String, ByVal Color As Integer)
Dim s As String

    s = vbNewLine & Msg
    frmMirage.txtChat.SelStart = Len(frmMirage.txtChat.Text)
    frmMirage.txtChat.SelColor = QBColor(Color)
    frmMirage.txtChat.SelText = s
    frmMirage.txtChat.SelStart = Len(frmMirage.txtChat.Text) - 1
End Sub
```

txtChat from frmMirage.txtChat.SelStart = Len(frmMirage.txtChat.Text) highlighting

Comment: Len(frmMirage.<font color="red">txtChat.Text</red>). I doubt there is a frmMirage.<font color ... property. Maybe you want Len("<font color=""red"">" & frmMirage.txtChat.Text & "</red>")

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the line below

```
frmMirage.txtChat.SelColor = QBColor(Color) -- VB6 textbox does not have a 'SelColor' prop
```

Maybe this (below) might be helpful

```
frmMirage.txtChat.BackColor = vbRed
```

Comment: [link]http://www22.zippyshare.com/v/10363813/file.html[/link]

This link to source. Your code not work ; /

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a standard TextBox control.

The standard TextBox control doesn't have a SelColor property. If you want to use a different color for you text you can change the standard TextBox control into a RichTextBox control